# How do I use the PC's headset for smartphone calls, when connected through USB?

Tags: usb, audio, desktop, smartphone, call

When my smartphone (Nokia 500) is connected to the desktop (Win7 x64) though USB, I want the smartphone audio to default to the PC headset for calls.

How do I do that?

Thanks.